# return image with name in autocomplete textbox search ajaxcontroltoolKit in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want search in asp.net  which return  name with image . As i am using AjaxControlToolKit , but it only returns the names  not the image ..

my autocomplete src code is this

```
  [WebMethod]

public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText)
{



    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=sharedmssql.znetindia.net,1234;Initial Catalog=jobandhotel;User ID=jobnhotel;Password=-pl,0okm");




    cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  ManageUser_JobSeeker WHERE KeySkills like   '" + prefixText + "%' ", conn);


    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables.Count == 0 || ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)


    return default(string[]);


    List<string> items = new List<string>(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {



         items.Add(row["JobSeekerName"].ToString()+ "<img src='ram.jpg' height='10' width='10'/>");


    }
    return items.ToArray();

}![i want serch like this as in linkedlen,   please  provide me a source code if you can][1]
```

Comment: Please check your image path is Correct or not then after you can use SPAN html element and inner html should be use table tr td structrue. then you can see your list.

Comment: sir .. please provede me the code still i am facing the problem